# Asignar span.innerText que empiece con un espacio en blanco

Tags: javascript, html5, regex

Yendo al grano: El último else devuelve un número entre el 10 y el 13 antecedido por un '.' Mi pregunta es cómo empezar con un espacio en blanco (ejemplo: ' 13' en lugar de '.13'). Gracias!

Contexto: Buenas, tengo esta función que me devuelve un número aleatorio entre el 1 y el 13. La función se ejecuta cada 147 milisegundos con un setInterval y en el html se visualizan todos esos números que van saliendo hasta que ejecuto el clearInterval. Le agregué el '0' para que visualmente ocuparan el mismo ancho los números que van cambiando. En el último else le agrego el '.' para lograr el mismo efecto (porque en la fuente que estoy usando el 0 es más ancho que el 1). Cómo puedo hacer para poner un espacio en lugar de un '.' ??

Pd.: Las fuentes monoespaciadas son todo lo que está bien, pero esta fuente es perfecta para el uso que le estoy dando en este caso en particular (Alegreya, para los curiosos).

```
let random = () => {

    let randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 13);

    if (span.innerText && span.innerText == randomNumber) {
        random();
    } else if (randomNumber <= 9) {
        span.innerText = '0' + randomNumber;
    } else {
        span.innerText = '.' + randomNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Usa un espacio en vez de un punto? Así: `span.innerText = ' ' + randomNumber;`

Comment: No da resultado eso

Comment: ¡Tienes razón! Curioso que no funcione, se aprende cada día.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece ser que no es tan sencillo como agregar el espacio por como el DOM obtiene/maneja los datos del elemento (?). Sin embargo, intenté un par de cosas y parece ser que sí funciona si utilizas el caracter unicode para el espacio (`/u00A0`).

```js
const span1 = document.getElementById("test");
const span2 = document.getElementById("test2");
const span3 = document.getElementById("test3");


let random = () => {

  let randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 13);


  span1.innerText = '.' + randomNumber;
  span2.innerText = ' ' + randomNumber;
  span3.innerText = '\u00A0' + randomNumber;

}


const letZero = () => {

}
```

```html
<p id="test"></p>
<p id="test2"></p>
<p id="test3"></p>
<button id="generate" onclick="random()"> Generar Numero</button>
```

Detalle adicional: Puedes agregar emojis usando este método (por eso se me ocurrió usarlo).

Comment: Excelente, funciona perfecto. Muchas gracias. Voy a tener que ver eso del unicode... nunca lo había escuchado, yo pensé que la solución venía por el lado de las regex